# Why find command doesn't pass all file as input to the -exec parameter?

Tags: linux, shell, find

There are all the files and symbolic links in the directory:

```
./02.tdf/IP_B186.tdf
./02.tdf/In_B186.tdf
./03.bed/IP_B186_vs_In_B186_peaks.xls.promoter_peak.bed
./03.bed/IP_B186_vs_In_B186_peaks.xls.bed
./01.genome/Harukei3_v1.41.fa
./01.genome/Harukei3_v1.41.gene.bed
./md5.txt
```

when I run  `find . -type f -o -type l -exec md5sum {} +  | sort > md5.txt`
I will get:

```bash
cat md5.txt
331a1bebdaf8b09fbdb6468b9c53bac3  ./01.genome/Harukei3_v1.41.fa
6354c1dfb5b0aff9620712ec17c271e3  ./01.genome/Harukei3_v1.41.gene.bed
```

When I run `find . -type f -o -type l | while read i; do md5sum $i >> md5.txt; done`
I wil get:

```bash
cat md5.txt
d9eb8d2ad4f0c03ca1dc9628e3562f01  ./02.tdf/IP_B186.tdf
c72eda337f2d75301baf125d6d64a5bc  ./02.tdf/In_B186.tdf
3ea65045235ed51efcc88af49d126a60  ./03.bed/IP_B186_vs_In_B186_peaks.xls.promoter_peak.bed
954484488dce3f5f18b7c06f6693f223  ./03.bed/IP_B186_vs_In_B186_peaks.xls.bed
331a1bebdaf8b09fbdb6468b9c53bac3  ./01.genome/Harukei3_v1.41.fa
6354c1dfb5b0aff9620712ec17c271e3  ./01.genome/Harukei3_v1.41.gene.bed
```

Thed second result is what I want, I want to know why the first script gives a so strang output.
Could someone help me ? Many thanks.

I also try `find . -type f -o -type l -exec md5sum {} \;  | sort > md5.txt`, but it gives the same output that I don't want.

Comment: You probably want `-xtype` rather than `-type`.

Comment: Is it a precedence issue? Do you need to group the `-o` conditions? e.g. `find . \( -type f -o -type l \) -exec ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard for `find` [states](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47) (formatting mine):

> The primaries can be combined using the following operators (in order of decreasing precedence):
>
> - `(` expression `)`
>
>   - True if expression is true.
> - `!` expression
>
>   - Negation of a primary; the unary NOT operator.
> - expression [ `-a` ] expression
>
>   - Conjunction of primaries; the AND operator is implied by the juxtaposition of two primaries or made explicit by the optional `-a` operator. The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is false.
> - expression `-o` expression
>
>   - Alternation of primaries; the OR operator. The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is true.
>
> If no expression is present, `-print` shall be used as the expression. Otherwise, if the given expression does not contain any of the primaries `-exec`, `-ok`, or `-print`, the given expression shall be effectively replaced by:
>
> `(` given_expression `)` `-print`

---

### `find . -type f -o -type l -exec md5sum {} +`

This has form *expression* `-o` *expression*, with expressions:

- `-type f`
- `-type l -exec md5sum {} +`

  - (which is form: *expression* `-a` *expression*)

Only the second produces output.

### `find . -type f -o -type l`

This also has form *expression* `-o` *expression*, with expressions:

- `-type f`
- `-type l`

Neither expression explicitly produces output. However, the final rule above applies, and the implied command is:

```
find \( -type f -o -type l \) -print
```

---

As @jqurious points out in the comments, to get your desired result, you should use parentheses:

```
find \( -type f -o -type l \) -exec md5sum {} +
```

Comment: Very clear explanation, thank you so much. :)